# Import javascript file after component is mounted

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

i am building spa using vuejs as the frontend and laravel as the backend, and i purcased some admin bootstrap template named [limitless](https://themeforest.net/item/limitless-responsive-web-application-kit/13080328) (very cool admin template by the way).

But there is the problem with this template that in the main javascript file (app.js in admin directory) there is this line

```
// Calculate min height
    function containerHeight() {
        var availableHeight = $(window).height() - $('.page-container').offset().top - $('.navbar-fixed-bottom').outerHeight();

        $('.page-container').attr('style', 'min-height:' + availableHeight + 'px');
    }

    // Initialize
    containerHeight();
```

and because i am using spa vuejs so i only include all js file in my admin.blade.php file like this

```
<!DOCTYPE Html>
<Html lang="{{ config('app.locale') }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no' name='viewport'>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <script>
        window.Laravel = <?php echo json_encode([
            'csrfToken' => csrf_token(),
        ]); ?>
    </script>
    <title>SIMO</title>
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
    <!-- icon-->
    <link rel="icon" href="{{asset('images/logo.png')}}" sizes="16x16">
    <link rel="icon" href="{{asset('images/logo.png')}}" sizes="32x32">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="{{asset('images/logo.png')}}"/>
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="{{asset('images/logo.png')}}" sizes="76x76" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="{{asset('images/logo.png')}}" sizes="120x120" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="{{asset('images/logo.png')}}" sizes="152x152" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="{{asset('images/logo.png')}}" sizes="180x180" />
    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300,100,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{asset('css/admin/icons/icomoon/styles.css')}}" >
    {{-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{asset('css/admin/icons/fontawesome/styles.min.css')}}" > --}}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{asset('css/admin/bootstrap.css')}}" >
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{asset('css/admin/core.css')}}" >
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{asset('css/admin/components.css')}}" >
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{asset('css/admin/colors.css')}}" >
    @yield('css')

    <!-- Html5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of Html5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/Html5shiv/3.7.0/Html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>
<div id="app"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('js/admin/plugins/loaders/pace.min.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('js/admin/libraries/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('js/admin/libraries/bootstrap.min.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('js/admin/plugins/loaders/blockui.min.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('js/admin/plugins/ui/nicescroll.min.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('js/admin/plugins/ui/drilldown.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('js/admin/plugins/buttons/hover_dropdown.min.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('js/admin/plugins/forms/selects/bootstrap_select.min.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('js/admin/plugins/ui/ripple.min.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('js/admin/app.js') }}"></script>

</body>
</Html>
```

and after inspecting the code i found out that it need div with class `page-container` and this div is located after header part so in my index.vue page i put it like this

```
<template>
<div>
   <div class="page-header">
     //here is header
   </div>
   <div class="page-container">
    //content
   </div>
</div>
</template>
```

so it will throw

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined
```

because when the page loaded it don't find any div with `page-container` class, since it not there yet.

And from what i read in vuejs documentation about lifecycle, this entire admin/app.js code should be run in mounted() or created() vuejs function. But from the example in documentation and around the internet it just used for run some javascript function but not include entire javascript file so it will be executed in there....

so my question is how to solve this? or for more simple way, how to add external css file and javascript file in component(this index.vue is called component right?) some people tell me to make it module and import it but i have no idea how to do that....

from what i know is i can download javascript plugin like moment from npm and it magically can be called within vue with `import moment from moment` but how about the local javascript files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you use your local javascript files at your component ,you should import it.
just like that:

```
// before you use your files in some components,you should package them
// your local files
export default {   //export your file
   your_function(){ // defined your function
   ...
   }
}

// now your can use it
// your component file

<script>
import local_file from 'your_file_relative_path'
//now you can use it in the hook function
created(){  //or other hook function
   local_file.your_function() //call your function
}

</script>
```

as for css file , your can also import it  at style tag inside

```
//your component file
<style>
  @import 'your_css_file_path' 
  //or use requrie
  require('your_css_file_path')
<style>
```

Other way, write your js code outside of export,it maybe work

```
   //xxx.vue
   <script>
   var your_code='your_code'
   var your_function=function(){

   }
   export default{

   }
   </script>
```

## update_1:

After a difficult battle,I use jQuery correctly in Vue.

First,you must make sure that you can **use jQuery by introducing instead of using script tag** which .**This is very important!!!**

the following is my way to introduce jQuery ,but my webpack is different from you,so do that in your way:

```
//package.json  //add the attributes and run npm install
"devDependencies": {
   "jquery" : "^2.2.3",
   ...
}

//webpack.base.conf.js
var webpack = require("webpack")
module.exports = {
   ...
    plugins: [ //use the plugin
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin('common.js'),
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            jQuery: "jquery",
            $: "jquery"
        })
    ]
}

//main.js,the file you instantiate Vue object just like your app.js
import $ from 'jquery'  //now you can use jQuery anywhere in the Vue files
...
const app = new Vue({
    router,
    render: h => h(Admin)
}).$mount('#app');
```

now you can use jQuery anywhere in the Vue files

```
//app.vue
<template>
    <div id="app">
        <router-view></router-view>
        <div class="page-container"></div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    //file name don't be like app.js in order to avoid conflict
    import yourApp from './yourApp.js'  
    export default {
        name: 'app',
        created() {
            yourApp.app_function()
           //now it can find .page-container class and not alert the error
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: sorry but my project is laravel with vuejs so my asset folder is in separate place from vuejs so how to get the right path?

Comment: This is embarrassing, I suggest you put the JS file in the vue project.
Beside, I see you we introduce many JS files in index.html, it maybe not good because it take up a lot of traffic.
I think you can introduce them when they are used.

Comment: thats the point, i want to introduce only JS file that have something to do with the current view, and i already tried it, i put all js file in there and import it... but still getting the same error.... just don;t get it

Comment: here i have my project in github https://github.com/t0n1zz/bkcuvue please note that this is laravel one so if you not familiar with laravel, the vue files is live in resources/assets/js and my index.html (in this case i use admin.blade.php) is located in resources/views and to compile it just run npm run watch in root directory

Comment: I ran NPM run watch, and after that I visited localhost://8020, nothing happened. How can I access your page?

Comment: oh i forgot to mention to access it add /admin/ in the url and it have some authentication but you can disabled it in router.js file in resources/assets/js directory

Comment: check out the update above and I hope it work for you.

Comment: where can i find webpack.base.conf.js?

Comment: Not necessarily the webpack.base.conf.js file,It's where you configure the webpack plugins